# Cable shield as ground conductor

Tags: emc

I have two circuits connected by a shielded cabled. The cable brings 3.3V DC and LVDS communication between the circuits. The shield is being used as the sole conductor for the reference ground to the load side of the circuit.

This doesn't seem right, I know for high frequency shielding the shield should be connected to ground at both ends, but isn't that based on the thought that the ground current is to be primarily carried by a separate conductor?

Should the cable be more like:

- Shield (drain)
- GND
- 3.3V
- TX_P
- TX_N

instead of:

- Shield (drain)
- 3.3V
- TX_P
- TX_N

Answer (score 2):

Consider signalling/data/telecom circuits that are phantom powered - power flows down the cables that carry the signals (and up the shield if it has one). These configurations work reasonably well providing the currents that power the device are kept smooth and don't have a frequency content (with significant power levels) approaching the signal power levels at their lowest frequency.

If this is kept in mind, this type of system can work. Inductors are normally used to couple power to the signal lines and inductors are also used to remove power from the signal line. The data has to be (say) manchester encoded to make sure it's minimum frequency is well above harmonics of the power current of course. Other encoding methods such as scrambling or FSK are also commonly used in these circumstances. Differential/balanced encoding of the data is also important (see below).

So, to answer your question, NO the cable carrying current through its screen/shield is perfectly OK providing the harmonic content of those power currents don't interfere with the data either by induction or, to a lesser extent, by capacitive coupling - note that the data lines in the question are presumed balanced and differential so this meets some of the criteria mentioned above.

Comment: Great response. The only downside to this specific application would be the mismatched current carrying capacity, shield is 36 awg, 3.3V is 28 awg.